# How to search name and delete node in doubly linked list in C?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I want to search the name in my doubly linked list and delete, but I have a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in the end.

```
typedef struct NODE {
  char *name;
  struct NODE *next;
  struct NODE *prev;
} node_t;

void delnode(struct NODE** head, char* search_name) {
                    struct NODE* search_node = 
                           (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                    struct NODE* current = *head;
                    search_node->name = search_name;
                    while(current->name!=search_name)
                        current = current->next;
                    current->prev->next = current->next;
                    current->next->prev = current->prev;
                    current->prev = NULL;
                    current->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `while(current->name!=search_name)` will compare the pointers - not the strings. Hence if it's two different instances of the string your loop will never end and result in a segfault.

Comment: In any case you may want to put another ending condition if the name is not found.

Comment: Also your `while` loop is not checking for reaching the end of the list when no matches are found. You need to break out of the loop if `current` is initially NULL (no elements in the list), or NULL after assigning `current->next` (no next element). That's what's really causing the segfault: NULL pointer access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and do not forget to update the value of `*head`. I will try to summarize all the comments as follows:

```
void delnode(struct NODE** head, char* search_name) {
    struct NODE* current;
    for(current=*head; current; current = current->next) {
        if (!strcmp(current->name, search_name)) {
            if (current->next)
                current->next->prev = current->prev;
            if (current->prev)
                current->prev->next = current->next;
            if (current == *head)
                *head = current->next;
            current->prev = NULL;
            current->next = NULL;
            free(current);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange way of phrasing an answer, to start with "and".

Comment: `head` could be NULL.

Comment: thank you, this is perfect for me. and yes, I did update the value of *head. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Yunnosch I wanted to say that I agree with the previous comments and I want to add my own, as well as offer an updated code taking into account all the comments. This is faster and shorter than disassembling each of the items.